# Add content form metabox to ribbon content PHP

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, ribbon

I want to show specific text from metabox in ribbon that is placed on photo.
And to show it only if I have text in metabox.

I have CSS ribbon:

```
.ribbon figure {position:relative;}
.ribbon figure:before {

    position:absolute;
    top:15px;
    right:0;
    background:#5fc8c2;
    padding:5px 10px;
    color:#fff;
    font-weight:700;
    z-index:2;
}
```

I have metabox for custom post types registered in the system.

```
$discount_text = $accommodation_obj->get_custom_field('discount_text', true);
```

And I can show it if there is text.

```
if (!empty($discount_text)) {
echo $discount_text ;
}
```

However it will not show the text inside a ribbon content.

I tried to add this:

```
if (!empty($discount_text)) {
echo $discount_text . '<div class="ribbon" >';
}
```

If I add content in css like:

```
content:"SALE";
```

it will show the text SALE properly, but that is static text and not what I want.
Any hint?

Comment: `echo $discount_text . '<div class="ribbon" >';` doesn't that make text outside of the ribbon ? have you checked html output in console ? what about the other way around -> `echo"<div class=\"ribbon\" >$discount_text<div>";` ?

Comment: Yes I am looking for a way to make text inside of a ribbon css. But this didn't work for me. The text is still before photo and no ribbon. If I put content: "SALE"; in CSS it will show the content and ribbon correctly. So it is working but can't style the discount text.

Comment: `this didn't work for me` won't help that much, we need to know if any error in html output, how it appears in your browser source -> please show this output

Comment: No errors in html output as I can see. This is actual output because this is the name of the ribbon class: `<div class='home-content-sidebar accommodation_item' >40%</div>` It doesn't shows the `home-content-sidebar accommodation_item` style. It is a kind of a widget showing some post info and feature image in a box. If I use `content:"any text here";` in css it wll show `any text here` correctly. But as I explained, it will not give me the `$discount_text` (40%) in style.

Comment: so, the expected HTML output is `<div class='home-content-sidebar accommodation_item' >40%</div>` and you get `<div class='' >40%</div>` right ?

Comment: No, I got what is expected. `<div class='home-content-sidebar accommodation_item' >40%</div>`. 40% is data extracted from metabox. And it is ok to be there. Everything is ok in html output, but it is not styled as should be as CSS is set. This `class='home-content-sidebar accommodation_item'` its not working as should be. As it is working if I put `content:"SALE";` in CSS part. Than it will show correct word SALE in ribbon.

Comment: then I recommand that you work around the `figure`css part of it